# required field is not working in asp dropdownlist

Tags: validation, dropdown, required

i have an form with some text fields and dropdowns.

I am using bootstrap which users jQuery. 
The problem is the required="required" attribute in the ASP dropdown control is not working.

Is working on text fields, but not no in dropdown.

here dont work:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="orderTypesDropDownList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" required="required" DataSourceID="purchaseOrderTypesDS" DataTextField="PurchaseOrderType" DataValueField="TypeID" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">-- SELECT --</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

But here works:

How can i make it works in the ASP dropdown like in the ASP textBox?

I was checking the DOM of the page after compile and looks like this:

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$userBudget$orderTypesDropDownList" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_userBudget_orderTypesDropDownList" class="form-control" required="required">
<option selected="selected" value="-- SELECT --">-- SELECT --</option>
<option value="8">AmEx PCard</option>
<option value="14">E-Victor Purchase</option>
<option value="13">In-House Job</option>
<option value="3">Internal Unit Request</option>
<option value="2">Invoice</option>
<option value="4">Journal Entry</option>
<option value="16">Material Move Request</option>
<option value="11">Material Request Tag</option>
<option value="12">Rapid Purchase</option>
<option value="17">Smart Buy Blanket PO</option>
<option value="6">Smart Buy PO</option>
<option value="15">Spare PO</option>
```

So its should be working, why is not working?

I am using ASP 4.0 framework with web forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first value should be empty when using "required" in a select. (value="")

Comment: Thanks dude! Working now!